# swift swipe recognizer doens't work at first swipe

Tags: swift

well here is my code
I want to have two functions for left swipe and right swipe
both functions work but only if I swipe twice...the first time nothing happens
thank you!

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    SwipeGesture.addTarget(self, action: "addSwipe")
}

func addSwipe() {
    let directions: [UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection] = [.Right, .Left]
    for direction in directions {
        let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipe:"))
        gesture.direction = direction
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}

func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
        print("swipe to close")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
        print("Swiped left")

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("chatAlbumViewController") as UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this code for: `SwipeGesture.addTarget(self, action: "addSwipe")` what is SwipeGesture? i would add the code in addSwipe to viewWillAppear, it doesn't look like you will reuse the method and always want it loaded on the view

Comment: @IBOutlet var SwipeGesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you need to swipe twice is becuase you have a gesture recognisor that adds the gesture recognisors, so the first swipe registers them and then the second actually does what you want.

to fix, change this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    SwipeGesture.addTarget(self, action: "addSwipe")
}
```

to

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.addSwipe()
}
```

and remove the outlet for the other one, it's not needed

Comment: great, if this answers your question please mark it as teh accepted answer by clicking the grey tick next to the answer. thanks